# Read string with accents from XML in UTF-8

Tags: php, xml, utf-8

I read a XML like this:

```
$arquivo = simplexml_load_string($str);
```

This XML is UTF-8:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

I want read this part:

```
<ii:RazaoSocial>UNIDOS SERVIçOS MéDICOS LTDA-ME</ii:RazaoSocial>
```

When I do echo of this part:

```
echo strtolower($Nfse->InfNfse->RazaoSocial->__toString());

Output:

unidos serviã§os mã©dicos ltda
```

When I use utf8_decode, like this:

```
echo strtolower(utf8_decode($Nfse->InfNfse->RazaoSocial->__toString()));

Output:

unidos servi?os m?dicos ltda
```

How I can recognize the accents?

Answer (score 0):

You might have more luck using multibyte string parsing.

Try: `echo mb_strtolower($Nfse->InfNfse->RazaoSocial->__toString());`

Answer (score 0):

If the file is really UTF-8, then you don't need to do anything special to decode it.

Where your script is likely going wrong, is during output. Make sure your output has the correct `<meta>` tag or `Content-Type` header that tells a browser to interpret the output as UTF-8.